# The power of the most powerful test...

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm stuck at the problem involving the most powerful tests. Here's the wording of a problem:

Random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n, n \geq 2$ are independent and identically distributed with density function $f(x) = \lambda x^{\lambda -1} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$, where $\lambda >0$. We observe the random variable $Z$ and consider the hypotheses:

- $H_0$: $Z$ has the same distribution as $-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln[X_i]$
- $H_1$: $Z$ has the same distribution as $-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \ln[X_i]$

The power $t$ of the most powerful test at the significance level $\alpha \in (0,1)$ satisfies the equation:

- (A) $\exp(- \frac{n-1}{\lambda t}) = \alpha$
- (B) $\sum_{k=0} ^ {n} \frac{1}{k!} \exp(- \frac{n-1}{\lambda t}) \left(\frac{n-1}{\lambda t}\right)^k=\alpha$
- (C) $1-\exp(- \frac{n-1}{\lambda t}) = \alpha$
- (D) $1-\exp(- \frac{n-1}{t}) = \alpha$
- (E) $\sum_{k=0} ^ {n} \frac{1}{k!} \exp(- \frac{n-1}{ t}) \left(\frac{n-1}{ t}\right)^k=1-\alpha$

I tried to find the distribution of $-\ln[X_i]$ and using the distribution function of $X_i$ as well as the expression $P(-\ln[X_i] \leq t)$ I found that it is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, which yields reformulated hypotheses:

- $H_0$: $Z$ ~ Gamma$(n,\lambda)$
- $H_1$: $Z$ ~ Gamma$(n-1,\lambda)$

Then I tried to use the Neyman-Pearson lemma:

$\frac{f_{\theta _1}(\mathbb{z})}{f_{\theta _0}(\mathbb{z})}=
\frac{   \frac{\lambda ^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)} z_1 ^{n-2} \exp(-\lambda z_1) \cdot ... \cdot  
\frac{\lambda ^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)} z_n ^{n-2} \exp(-\lambda z_n)   }{
\frac{\lambda ^{n}}{\Gamma(n)} z_1 ^{n-1} \exp(-\lambda z_1) \cdot ... \cdot  
\frac{\lambda ^{n}}{\Gamma(n)} z_n ^{n-1} \exp(-\lambda z_n)   } = \frac{(n-1)^n}{\lambda^n \prod _{i=1}^{n} z_i}$

This is the point where I got stuck, I'm not sure what to do with the product of Gamma distributions. Can anyone help?